# How to zip whole folder into single file in android

Tags: android

I am currently using below code to zip the folder , but unfortunately i am unable to zip the cache folder, if i try to do i only creates a dummy zip file...
But it working fine with any other folder located in internal and external memory..
I used permissions to write and read internal files, still i face this weird issue

public void zip() {

```
     String p = "/data/data/com.example.****/cache/";
     Date now = new Date();
     File dir = new File (p,"up"); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
      String fileName = formatter.format(now);
     String _zipFile  =p +"up/"+fileName+".zip"; 
   try  { 
     BufferedInputStream origin = null; 
     FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile); 
     ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest)); 
    File fileDir = new File("/data/data/com.example.****/cache/****/");
                 String[] _files = fileDir.list(); 
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < _files.length ; i++  )
     { 
           _files[i] = fileDir + "/"+ _files[i];
     }
     byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER]; 
     for(int i=0; i < _files.length; i++) { 
       Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]); 
       FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]); 
       origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER); 
       ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1)); 
       out.putNextEntry(entry); 
       int count; 
       while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) { 
         out.write(data, 0, count); 
       } 
       origin.close(); 
     } 
     out.close(); 
   } catch(Exception e) { 
     e.printStackTrace(); 
   } }
```

Comment: Can you please show the exception you have?

Comment: Do not hardcode paths. Use `getCacheDir()` on some `Context`, such as your `Activity`.

Comment: I tried with each and everything, still no luck :(

Comment: @MahdiHijazi java.io.FileNotFoundException:/data/data/com.example.***/**.png : open failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)                                                        and yes i disconnected the mobile from computer and tried, i didnt mounted my internal storage, still i am facing the issue and i rememeber that i used the permission to read and write internal files